# Is the Expression "straight from the horse's mouth" Offensive?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage, expressions, american-english

Is the phrase "straight from the horse's mouth" offensive, or likely to be perceived as offensive when said about someone who is present? For instance, after having confirmed some piece of information from someone, you tell them: "ah, I have now heard it straight from the horse's mouth!". I ask this because it is generally considered offensive to compare people to animals, though in some cultures more so than others.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63717/discussion-on-question-by-borat-sagdiyev-is-the-expression-straight-from-the-ho).

Answer (score 6):

I fail to see how it could be the slightest bit offensive, since, if properly used, it is anonymous, and the horse you got the info from is never identified.

The idiom originated with horse race betting where a bit of insider information that was "straight from the horse's mouth" was ostensibly from the horse itself, and thus, by implication, from someone very close to the horse -- jockey, horse trainer, stable boy, etc.  It would obviously be very poor form to identify your source in such a case, and so the source remains anonymous.

Comment: There's nothing anonymous about the situation in the question. Person A has enquired of Person B whether something is correct, and having been told, A says to B that he has now heard it from the horse's mouth (that is, B). A is actually calling B a horse. This might actually be Not An Answer, because it appears not to address the question asked.

Comment: This really doesn't seem to address the question asked.

Comment: Just about any statement can be perceived as offensive.  This is especially likely if the listener is not familiar with the idioms being used.

Answer (score -5):

Yes, comparison to a horse may be offensive.  The flattering aspect is rather hollow because the expression refers to a racing tip from the highest source (the horse itself), which is an impossible situation.  {unless Mr. Ed}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63718/discussion-on-answer-by-ami-is-the-expression-straight-from-the-horses-mouth).